# Card edge connector "read out" meaning

Tags: connector, edge-connector

I'm looking for a card edge connector to short the pads on one side of a PCB card to the pads immediately opposite them on the other side of the card. Digikey specifies an attribute called "read out" to indicate whether there are one or two contacts on the other side of the connector (opposite the female mating portion where the card slides in). Here's an image with a single read out, to further clarify.

[image]

It is single read out because there is only one eyelet for each two adjacent positions, instead of two eyelets (one connected to each pad).

My question is: does single read out mean that the connectors on each side are shorted together and the eyelet connects to each? Or, is the eyelet only shorted to one connector and it's assumed that the pads are shorted on the PCB?

I was looking at this [EDAC connector](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/edac-inc/306-010-500-102/107635). I could, of course, get a dual read out and solder them together myself. But, it's a bit easier if I don't have to. If this isn't standard practice/terminology and I should contact digikey or the manufacturer, that would also be useful to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The datasheet for the EDAC 306/316/356 connectors you linked shows that those connectors do contact both sides of the inserted PC board.

Comment: Huh, I don't see it for some reason. If it's not too much trouble, would you mind quoting or posting a picture of where it indicates that?

Comment: On page 1 of the datasheet, see the "In-contact polarizing key" illustration.  Also,on page 2, the "Section through contact position" illustration.  It is possible that there are some edge connectors that only contact one side of the board.